# Error about uudecode when trying to extract jsapi.jar in sphinx4

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sphinx4, jsapi

I am trying to setup environment for sphinx4 in Ubuntu 12.04. While extracting  JSAPI.JAR in lib directory from terminal I get following error:

when trying to accept the BCL :

```
Accept (y/n)?: y 
x - creating lock directory 
x - extracting jsapi.jar (binary) jsapi.sh: line 257: uudecode: command not found 
restore of jsapi.jar failed 
jsapi.jar: MD5 check failed
```

according to the tutorial here ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSnjlmfkrG0 ) if i am getting errors then i am missing some required dependencies....
Can anyone please help that which dependencies do i need and how to install them.

note:
I am a starter in ubuntu so do not know much about it, therefore please give a detailed answer

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message says you uudecode tool is missing. You need to install it

uudecode is a part of sharutils package, so `apt-get install sharutils` should help you

Also jsapi is really outdated, you should not use it.

Comment: thanks for the help....
and just for helping others i will tell that I was getting some lock errors so I had to use command as    sudo apt-get install sharutils

Comment: I import all the external Jar files in eclipse, but eclipse doesn't recognize most of the packages therefore I can't run the demo projects.. I am following the steps exactly like the tutorial I have mentioned in the question. please help if you can.